# Dell OMSA Storage Auto Patrol Read Schedule

Tags: dell, dell-perc, dell-openmanage

My Dell servers with Perc H700 Controller are automatically performing periodic Patrol Reads.

Is there a way to set schedule for these checks?

Comment: Keep in mind that these are designed to take place as a low-priority operation. If you have a large amount of production I/O taking place during a patrol read, it's going to take high priority over the patrol read.

Comment: It's configurable, but I want to shift it to the nighttime operation, when server is idle. I prefer it to be 90% at nighttime than 5% at daytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control Patrol Reads if it is set to run automatically. You will have to switch to manual and schedule checks. From OMSA CLI:

Use

`omreport storage controller` to find controller Id.

Set Patrol Read Mode to Manual:

`omconfig storage controller action=setpatrolreadmode controller=XX mode=manual` where XX is correct controller Id

Command to schedule (to run Patrol Read):

`omconfig storage controller action=startpatrolread controller=XX`

Further reading:

[Server Administrator Storage Management User’s Guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_software/esuprt_ent_sys_mgmt/dell-opnmang-srvr-admin-v7.2_User%27s%20Guide2_en-us.pdf)

[Dell OpenManage Server Administrator Version 7.2 Command Line Interface Guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_software/esuprt_ent_sys_mgmt/dell-opnmang-srvr-admin-v7.2_Reference%20Guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: yeps, came to the same conclusion. looks like i must to add this command to the cron.

Thanks for the answer